# How to change the existing autofiled id to custom Integer primary key in django - Sqlite3?

Tags: django, database, sqlite, django-models, django-migrations

We didn't decide any primary key before creating the database and Django created a custom autoincrement primary key called 'id'. We have 20 tables with this primary key.

Now, I want to migrate from this auto-increment 'id' primary key to a custom integer primary key without auto-increment. Also, I would like to keep the name of the new primary key as 'id' itself.

What is the shortest and easier way of migrating without changing the existing id?

Will this work?

If I change the SQLite database (remove auto increment)

```
CREATE TABLE "users" (`id`  integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `name`  varchar ( 5 ) NOT NULL, `place` varchar ( 5 ) NOT NULL);
```

Add this line in my model

```
id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

After this, I can use makemigrations and migrate ?

DB used: SQLite3

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: You *can't* not have an auto incrementing integer primary key in a sqlite table without making it `WITHOUT ROWID` (though you can assign any unused integer to it when inserting a row). Some reading: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid  https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html

Comment: yeah, thank you. What all changes have to be made from Django side.

Comment: Not a clue. Not even sure what django is.